# sending multiple commands with batch

Tags: batch-file

I'd like to send the command `dir & pause` to a separate cmd window with start, but I can't seem to find out how. I have tried `start & dir & pause`, but a new window pops up without running dir and pause. Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the first `&` and escape the second.

```
start dir ^& pause
```

You're starting a new command window and parsing it the command `dir & pause`.

`&` is used to run multiple commands on the same line.